# How to add a value to an element of an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

How can I add value to appropriate element of an array?
E.g. if I have created an int array

```
int[] scores = new int[4];
```

And I want to add the value '3' to the first element in the 'scores' array (index 0).

Can you advice on how do this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 3):

Array supports index based access. Simply do:

```
scores[0] += 3;
```

Comment: scores[0] += 3; means  scores[0] = scores[0] + 3; the compound addition assignment operator is just a shorter way to code it. Perhaps its good to know for Nizami Khalilbayli :)

Comment: Thank yo very much. Then, how can I print the result.  System.out.println("Team has " +  scores[0] " + " points") seems incorrect, and I cant find the better way

Comment: System.out.println("Team has " + scores[0] + " points") .. Double quotes are for strings not for operators.